# Java - File Reading into an Array Error

Tags: java, io

I'm doing an assignment for school (so I can unfortunately not use third party libraries) and the goal is to read a csv file into an array, process it in a different method, and print it in another. This is what I have so far but I get the error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<String> to Collection<? extends String[]>.
```

Here is my code:

```
package client.java;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class Client{

String file = "bank-Detail.csv";
ArrayList<String[]> bank = new ArrayList<>();

public Client(String file) {
    this.file = file;
}

public void readData() throws IOException { 
    int count = 0;
    String file = "bank-Detail.txt";
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            bank.addAll(Arrays.asList(line.split(",")));
```

The line (Arrays.asList(line.split(","))); is where I get the error.

```
            String[] entries = line.split(",");

            String[][] numbers = (String[][]) bank.toArray(new String[bank.size()][12]);

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    }
}

public void processData() {


}

public void printData() {

}
```

Comment: Change to `bank.add(line.split(","));`

Comment: `Arrays.asList()` is converting from `String[]` to `List<String>`. `bank.addAll()` expects a `List<String[]>`. Maybe you mean to call `bank.add(line.split(","))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayList<String[]> bank` is a list of arrays, so instead of doing

`bank.addAll(Arrays.asList(line.split(",")));`

you just need to do

`bank.add(line.split(","));`

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))'s javadoc for split method, it returns an array of `String` which is what we need to add into the list.

Answer (score 0):

Each entry of your list `bank` is an arrray of `String`. But
But at this line

```
bank.addAll(Arrays.asList(line.split(",")));
```

You are trying to add a list of string `List<String>` to `bank` using `addAll`. But if you want to use `addAll` you have to add `List<String []>`. 
There is a small fix to your problem:

```
bank.add(line.split(","))
```

As `line.split(",")` will return an array of `String`.
And you are good to go.